# JDBC Statement cancelled due to time out or client request

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTimeoutException: Statement cancelled due to time out or client request
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1442)
```

Some code:

```
@Override
public synchronized ResultSet query(String s) throws SQLException {     
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        statement.setQueryTimeout(3);
```

So I'm saving user data on SQL and this sometimes happens, it's very rare, but still. I would like to know why this could be happening.

Answer (score 1):

Your client Open a connection to your Service or database.

By default, there is a timeout set, sometimes about 30 sec, in your apache server or Php... depends of what you use. Maybe mysql itself.

So, if your request is longer that 30 sec, the connection is stop, and you get this answer.

Hope this help you ;)

For more information, please give us your configuration : client , server type, apache or not, services...

Comment: Updated the post, my query timeout is set to 3 sec. But I would like to know why is it timing out?

Comment: It's like 1 out of 100 chance this happens.

Comment: So here i can't tell you exactly why happened. The only things we can affirm, it's sometimes, your request need more than 3 seconds to complete. It will depends on your database load, size of dataset, the paremter you give to your research... Maybe you database is in pool mode and no thread available ? You should read or post the database detail log, not only the service one.